# uWSGI unique timer python decorator

Tags: uwsgi, python-decorators

I would like to run a cron-like command with python decorators that needs to be unique (so that if the previous process is still running it doesn't start a new process) with uwsgi.

taking a look at the documentation (http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html) i saw that i can do something like this

task.py

```
from uwsgidecorators import *

@timer(600)   #every 10 minutes
def myfunction(signum):
    pass
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
...
import=task
...
```

but this way it is not unique like if i do something like this (following the documentation http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Cron.html)

task.py

```
...
all_my_tasks
...
```

uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
...
cron2 = minute=-10,unique=1 python path/to/task.py
...
```

Isn't there a way to do this using uwsgi's decorators and timer instead of cron?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the uWSGI locking api:

```
   from uwsgidecorators import *

   @timer(600)   #every 10 minutes
   def myfunction(signum):
       if uwsgi.is_locked(): return
       uwsgi.lock()
       ....
       uwsgi.unlock()
```

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Locks.html

Comment: I need to pass the timer duration as variable is it possible?